# npx create-react-app command is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, environment-variables, npx

`npx create-react-app my-app` is not working
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

can you please run

""" npm cache clean --force   """

Maybe you can also try  delete package.json and run """  npm install """"  as a clean setup

Comment: I've tried this before. it's not working!